# Replace the current url without reloading the page

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

**Using react 16, react-router 4.**

My domain is suppose "https://www.xyz.c". I'm having anchor tag which should redirect to "https://www.xyz.c/some-path" without reloading the page.

1. I can implement it using `<NavLink>` and `<Link>` with `to="/some-path"`. However, I need complete url to be shown in DOM (why? Well, on side note, I'm using itemProp for schema for which I want full path in anchor tag)
2. Implementing it with `<a>` and `props.history` tag like following causes to again replace with relative url, i.e. it becomes `https://www.xyz.c/https://www.xyz.c/some-path` in the url.

```
<a data-url="https://www.xyz.c/some-path" onClick={this.onClick}>Label</a>

onClick = e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  this.props.history.push(urlFromDataSet);
}
```

This seems impossible with `<Navlink>`, `<Link>` or `<a> + props.history`, since the policy is that `history.replace, or history.push` works on url with same origin. My url is also of same origin, however, I'm giving full path in href.

However, facebook is achieving the same in its header (Check on FB by going to home page, **once loaded completely**, then Click on your own profile button in header. It doesn't reload the page.)

How can we do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are half there, you can use `URL` API to get the pathname of your `data-url` attribute then push it.

```
const url = new URL(dataUrl) 
this.props.history.push(url.pathname)
```

More information about URL API: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL

Comment: Nice solution. IE 11 doesn't support URL though.